# What does the force field flow setting do?

Tags: physics, force-fields

What does the force field flow setting do? How is it typically used?

[image]

Please provide examples.

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/force_fields.html) says

> Flow Convert effector force into air flow velocity.

A quick test shows that it slows down the movement of particles but does not attract or repell them:

[image]

So my interpretation is it adds air resistance.

Comment: shouldn't 'flow' be renamed 'slow sim down setting'?...